# LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol "class ATL::CStringT..."

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am recieving the following error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > __cdecl messageForCode(int,class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >)" (?messageForCode@@YA?AV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@HV12@@Z)    MyUIDlg.obj
Error   2   fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\my-project\MyUI\Release\MyUI.exe
```

`messageForCode` is defined within a project `MyLibrary` that is compiled into a static library. This library doesn't depend on MFC and so includes CString using "#include ". It compiles fine by itself.

`MyUI` is an .exe project that fails to compile due to the above error. It uses MFC. One theory I have is that there is a conflict between the CString in MFC and the one in `atlstr.h`. I tried linking both statically and dynamically to ATL in the settings of both projects, but I couldn't resolve the error.

Answer (score 1):

Is messageForCode implemented in C or in C++? In case it is implemented in C you need to wrap its declaration with 'extern "C"'.